# How to capture onhover of a element overlapping a button?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hover

I'm using react and I'm trying to create a footer element, that displays some information on one side of the screen.
When the footer is hovered I want it to move to the other side of the screen in order for whats behind it to be visible.

A good example of this is the loading footer of chrome. when you move the mouse over it, it moves to the right side (and when you move out of it, it returns to the left again).

[image]

I'm currently struggling to make it so the footer ishover events are working and at the same time whats behind it is still clickable. The problem occurs because if the footer has `pointerEvent: "none"` the hover event doesn't work, and if the footer doesn't have `pointerEvent: "none"` then a button behind it isn't clickable...

[image]

I've created a minimal [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-minsky-7yei2?file=/src/App.js:746-752) to recreate the problem.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: In your codesandbox, is the button supposed to be under the moving div? So the button is revealed after hover? Or is the button supposed to be inside the moving div?

Comment: yes, it supposed to be under. the footer is always displayed in the page and button is the "content" of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo, I did it like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
onst [isMaskHoverd, setIsMaskHoverd] = useState(false);

return (
<div className="App">
  <div
    onMouseOver={() => setIsMaskHoverd(true)}
    onMouseOut={() => setIsMaskHoverd(false)}
    className={isMaskHoverd ? "footer footer__hover" : "footer"}
  >
    Footer
  </div>
  {/* It is clickable now :) */}
  <button className="btn" onClick={() => alert("clicked!")}>
    Click me
  </button>
  <p className="">masked hovered: {isMaskHoverd ? "true" : "false"} </p>
 </div>
 );
 }
```

and in styles.css I made those classes:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 background-color: black;
}

.App {
 position: relative;
 height: 100vh;
 }

.btn {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   padding: 20px;
 }

 .footer {
   background-color: white;
   padding: 20px;
   text-align: center;
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 2;
  }

 .footer__hover {
   right: 0;
  }
```

So now when u mouse over your footer as I called it(I couldnt stand those "asasas" things xD) class `footer__hover` is apllied and it changes its position to the right side and when you move out the mouse than only class footer with basic styling is applied so it's going back to the `left: 0` position and covering the button :D

Comment: did you try to run that, because I'm pretty sure all you will get is the footer flashing back and forth. because when it moves ishover = false then it moves back, and repeat...

Comment: Yes I did, u said in the question that u want it to get back when u're not hovering over it anymore the same as chrome loading bar in the example so it's working like this

Comment: After some testing I got your solution to work for me. there is a really weird issue that if the dev tools is open the footer flashes back and forth. really weird. anyway, thank you!

Comment: Hmm, maybe its happening because dev-tools do smth with inappropriate with page height and postion things are breaking, but I'm glad it works overall :D